# Laravel 5 how to set hosted website on development mode

Tags: laravel-5

How do I set my hosted Laravel site such that an attempt to visit any page of the website should display a message like: "Sorry, Website is under development, Will be available soon". it may be a dumb question but am new to this.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify

> yourLaravelDirectory/public/.htaccess

and add this rule to it

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com [R=permanent,L]
```

so now onwords all your traffic will redirect to this new domain..

make sure you have one html page that says "Sorry, Website is under development, Will be available soon" hosted at **www.newdomain.com**